# Forcing ClickOnce application update on Windows Startup?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that should automatically check for updates before the application starts. If I start the application manually this also works perfectly.

However I have also added a registry entry to start the application at windows startup and in this case the check for an update is not performed and the application starts just as if there would be no update - I guess because by the time the application starts the connection to the network drive on which the ClickOnce application installation is published is not yet established.

As a workaround I tried to manually force the application in my code by calling this after my MainWindow is already loaded:

```
private void checkforupdate() 
{
    try
    {

        ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

        if (ad.CheckForUpdate())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update available!");
            ad.Update();               
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

However for some reason this code still only triggers an update when I start the application manually, when it's started automatically on Windows start nothing happens. 
The part of my code where I call checkforupdate is after there was already a few things loaded from the very same drive where the ClickOnce installation files are published so the connection must be established by then.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: the code certainly works/runs, now if the update happens or not, that's another thing, seeing how you're managing it, if it's over network, then if there's no connection for the update to happen, the application shouldn't run ? or make your adjustments for it to wait till there's an available connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that I was having a severe misunderstanding of how the update of a ClickOnce application works: In the registry entry which starts the program at Windows start-up I referred to the .exe file in the mysterious Users\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0.... folders - while this does work of course for starting the application itself it does not have anything to do with the update functionality itself.
The update only happens when referring to ClickOnce Application reference (.appref-ms) Shortcut on the Desktop.